# How to disable auto-start of "Node.js: Server-side JavaScript" when using Adobe Dreamweaver?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dreamweaver, cpu-usage, autostart

How can I disable auto-start of "Node.js: Server-side JavaScript" process when every time using Adobe Dreamweaver?

The main reason I want it to not auto-start is this process utilize my CPU about 40%, causing my laptop's temperature high.

Besides, I don't think I need it, because nothing happen every time I end this process.

This process also will kept running even I close the Dreamweaver.

My location of node.exe is

> *C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Creative Cloud\CCXProcess\libs*

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why do you have node js there?

Comment: I don't know, it start along with Dreamweaver automatically.

Comment: I just noticed that node.js is running in the background on my windows computer 100% of the time, simply because Adobe wants to check if there's any update or if my license is correct. That's insane.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: One suggestion in [Adobe Forums](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2243475) was to log out of CC. Instead, I disabled all the CC auto-updating services that run when my PC starts up. Here are directions on [how to disable startup programs in Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/74523/how-to-disable-startup-programs-in-windows/).

Hypothesis: I couldn't find any documentation specifically about Adobe CC and node.js, but I believe its being used as part of the their software update process.

Background: My PC at work has been very sluggish and freezing a lot recently, so I checked the Task Manager I saw that there were two node.js processes running. I use node.js as a stand-alone product for web development/programming, but it doesn't run on startup.

To troubleshoot, I uninstalled node.js, removed all related files on my system, confirmed all references to it in `%PATH%` environment variables were removed, updated system registry, cleared all caches, and finally rebooted. None of this resolved the issue.

I don't know why I didn't do the following to being: I right-clicked on the process in the Task Manager, selected "Open File Location" and found the .exe within Adobe CC folders. Repeating this, I found the same for the second process in the Task Manager. A google search brought me here and to the Adobe Forums.

In retrospect, my company switched to CC in Dec. 2016, and I mainly use it for Photoshop. This is around the time my system began experiencing performance problems, so more than likely that's when the node.js processes began running on system startup.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What did you do when you find the node.exe in adobe cc folder?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Creative Cloud\CCLibrary\js\server` to whatever you want, and then rename `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Creative Cloud\CCLibrary\libs` to whatever you want. Press the buttons <kbd>Window</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and enter `msconfig`. Now, click on the startup tab button and uncheck all the `adobe` named services. Then click apply and OK and restart your PC.

Answer (score 1):

open task manager and go to details, select node.exe and terminate the process. then it will terminate the node processes which aren't terminated when you end processes from the processes tab.